# Second level UL width issue - css only

Tags: css, menu, drop-down-menu, html-lists

I'm having an issue with trying to get the second level UL to have a 100% width based off of the parent LI and not the first level UL like it does now.  I'm trying to only use css if possible too.  The reason I'm trying to figure this out, is so that I can then center the dropdown under the parent.

To best understand, I'm trying to mimic this nav dropdown when you hover over MEN: http://us.gant.com/

```
<ul> <----first level
  <li>
    <ul> <----second level
    <li></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: width: 100% things can only go of the most recent element in the tree for which the width is known.  If you don't have explicitly specified widths, it will just go up the tree until it does find something.  To get this kind of centered behavior easily, I don't know an easy way, but I can think of some complicated ones that seem kind of ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the the width of the parent `li` for this.
So do something like this:

```
ul li {
    width: 50px;
}

ul li li {
    width: auto; /* reset width */
}
```

Now the `ul` of the submenu has the same width of the `li`, because the `li` it the first ancestor with width specified.

Comment: the problem with that though, is that the parent level li can't have a defined width, since all the links are of different letter length.